# Tornadofx CSS Seleccted row

Tags: css, kotlin, tornadofx

I am trying to change the background color selected row and the same for a listview like when I do `cell{backgroundColor += Color.BLACK}` that works but it removes or atlest makes the selection color black aswell I have tried the below but that dossnt work sadly.  Thank you for your time!

```
val tableView by cssclass()

tableView {
    tableRowCell {
        selected {
            backgroundColor += Color.RED
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the and() function

```
    tableView {
        tableRowCell {
            and(selected) {
                backgroundColor += Color.GREEN
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes thx , I figured it out but forogt about this post. Thx tho!